# Spring resource resolver with different maven modules

Tags: java, spring

So for our test structure we currently have a base module in which we have some of our common configuration files etc (example: ds.properties). Now I'm currently running tests in a different module and I'm trying to load all .properties files (to get all the configurations) and I was using

```
(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(getClass().getClassLoader())).getResources("classpath:*.properties")
```

Now this is only finding alpha.properties (the property file in my module). Is there a way to get the property files in all modules?

Some stuff I have already tried:

```
(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(getClass().getClassLoader())).getResources("classpath:ds.properties")
```

Returns the ds.properties that I want but obviously not auth.properties.

```
(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(getClass().getClassLoader())).getResources("classpath*:*.properties")
```

Again only alpha.properties

```
(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(getClass().getClassLoader())).getResources("classpath*:**/*.properties")
```

Returns alpha.properties and a bunch of .properties files from the jre that I do not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm too lazy atm to find the reference in the documentation, but it's essentially this:

Top-level classpath-scan is not finding all resources matching a pattern. The reason is written in the docs.

Put your property files in a package (src/main/resources/somefolder for maven) and adapt your scan path to it and it should work as expected. (classpath*:somefolder/*.properties)

### For completeness: From the docs

Please note that classpath*: when combined with Ant-style patterns will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the pattern starts, unless the actual target files reside in the file system. This means that a pattern like " classpath*:*.xml`" will not retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the root of expanded directories. This originates from a limitation in the JDK’s`ClassLoader.getResources() method which only returns file system locations for a passed-in empty string (indicating potential roots to search).

Ant-style patterns with " `classpath:`" resources are not guaranteed to find matching resources if the root package to search is available in multiple class path locations. This is because a resource such as

com/mycompany/package1/service-context.xml
may be in only one location, but when a path such as

classpath:com/mycompany/**/service-context.xml
is used to try to resolve it, the resolver will work off the (first) URL returned by getResource("com/mycompany");. If this base package node exists in multiple classloader locations, the actual end resource may not be underneath. Therefore, preferably, use " `classpath*:`" with the same Ant-style pattern in such a case, which will search all class path locations that contain the root package.

Comment: Seems a bit weird for spring to not support top level scan. I did not want to use sub folders since then resource bundle starts complaining when looking for these files

Comment: I use this approach for several projects and i never saw a "complain"?

Comment: your answer is correct. As much as I hate this limitation. You don't happen to know any other library that would help avoid this limitation?

Comment: If you know what you search for i think its not too much work to implement it yourself. You will need to find all jars and scan from there on.